# How to change list into HTML table ? (Python)

Tags: python, html

This is what I have done when there is no HTML codes

```
from collections import defaultdict

hello = ["hello","hi","hello","hello"]
def test(string):
    bye = defaultdict(int)
    for i in hello:
        bye[i]+=1
    return bye
```

And i want to change this to html table and This is what I have try so far, but it still doesn't work

```
 def test2(string):
    bye= defaultdict(int)
    print"<table>"
    for i in hello:
        print "<tr>"
        print "<td>"+bye[i]= bye[i] +1+"</td>"
        print "</tr>"
    print"</table>"
    return bye
```

​

Comment: It still doesnt work.>Traceback (most recent call last):
    print "<td>"+bye[i]= bye[i] +1+"</td>"
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what was your expected output here?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I want the same output as the first one, but with an addition of HTML code

Comment: Why are you returning before your function finishes?

Comment: @ErikaSawajiri There's a difference between first and second, you didn't print anything in first one. Post the expected html output to make the question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count occurrences in a list, then use this information to create the html table. 
Try this:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

hello = ["hello","hi","hello","hello"]
counter= Counter(hello)
bye = defaultdict(int)
print"<table>"
for word in counter.keys():
    print "<tr>"
    print "<td>" + str(word) + ":" + str(counter[word]) + "</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    bye[word] = counter[word]
print"</table>"
```

The output of this code will be (you can change the format if you want):

```
>>> <table>
>>> <tr>
>>> <td>hi:1</td>
>>> </tr>
>>> <tr>
>>> <td>hello:3</td>
>>> </tr>
>>> </table>
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 2):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

hello = ["hello","hi","hello","hello"]

def test2(strList):
  d = defaultdict(int)
  for k in strList:
    d[k] += 1
  print('<table>')
  for i in d.items():
    print('<tr><td>{0[0]}</td><td>{0[1]}</td></tr>'.format(i))
  print('</table>')

test2(hello)
```

**Output**

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>hi</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>hello</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a variable in the middle of a print statement.  You also can't concatenate string types and integer types in a print statement.

```
print "<td>"+bye[i]= bye[i] +1+"</td>"
```

Should be

```
bye[i] = bye[i] + 1
print "<td>"
print bye[i]
print '</td>'
```

And your `return` statement comes before the final `print`, so it will never print.

Full function

```
def test2(string):
    bye= defaultdict(int)
    print"<table>"
    for i in hello:
        print "<tr>"
        bye[i] = bye[i] + 1
        print "<td>"
        print bye[i]
        print '</td>'
        print "</tr>"
        print"</table>"
        return bye
```

That would be an exact, working translation of your code, but I'm not sure why you are going about it that way.  `bye` is pointless here, as you are just printing 1 everytime

Answer (score 1):

Python `collections` module contains [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) function, that do exactly, what is needed:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> hello = ["hello", "hi", "hello", "hello"]
>>> print Counter(hello)
Counter({'hello': 3, 'hi': 1})
```

Now, you want to generate html. Better way is to use existing libraries for this. For example [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). You just need to install it, for example using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):

```
pip install Jinja2
```

Now, the code will be:

```
from jinja2 import Template
from collections import Counter

hello = ["hello", "hi", "hello", "hello"]

template = Template("""
<table>
    {% for item, count in bye.items() %}
         <tr><td>{{item}}</td><td>{{count}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
""")

print template.render(bye=Counter(hello))
```